# Qual é a politica de crescimento da stack da classe java?

Tags: java, stack

Estou a fazer um trabalho sobre diferentes stacks e o que estou a estudar, aumenta o seu tamanho para o dobro quando vamos introduzir o (2^n+)1 elemento.

Mas qual é a politica de crescimento da java.util.Stack e java.util.ArrayDeque?

Comment: Você está se referindo a `java.util.Stack` e `java.util.ArrayDeque`?

Comment: Sim @VictorStafusa

Answer (score 2):

## Stack

A classe `java.util.Stack` estende `java.util.Vector`, o que vai definir grande parte de sua funcionalidade.

`Vector` permite especificar em seu construtor tanto a capacidade inicial como o incremento do vetor interno quando a capacidade é excedida, porém tal construtor não está disponível na subclasse `Stack`.

Isto significa que o vetor interno sempre vai iniciar com a quantidade de elementos padrão, que é `10`, e dobrar de tamanho ao expandir: `20`, `40`, `80`, ...

Entretanto, o método `ensureCapacity(n)` pode forçar um crescimento mais acelerado. Basicamente, o método expande o vetor para garantir que ele possa receber pelo menos mais `n` elementos sem estourar a capacidade. Na implementação atual, o método primeiro verifica se dobrar a capacidade é suficiente, caso contrário ele redimensionar o vetor interno para `capacidade atual + n`. Isto também significa que não é possível expandir o vetor em menos do que o seu dobro, não ser criar uma implementação alternativa.

## ArrayDeque

Já a classe `java.util.ArrayDeque` terá sempre o tamanho do vetor interno sendo uma potência de `2`, como declara sua documentação.

## Alternativa

Para um crescimento linear, pode ser utilizada a classe `java.util.LinkedList`, a qual implementa `java.util.Deque`, a mesma interface implementada por `java.util.arrayDeque`.

## Comparações

Nunca é demais lembrar que cada implementação tem suas vantagens e desvantagens.

Por exemplo, as implementações baseadas em vetores são mais velozes para acesso aleatório e para inserção de vários elementos em sequência, principalmente quando a quantidade é conhecida e desde que a quantidade não seja tão grande quanto, digamos, metade da memória disponível.

Listas baseadas em cadeias de elementos pode ser necessárias quando a lista é muito grande, ocupando a maior parte da memória e é alterada bastante frequentemente de modo não é possível usar vetores, já que  fazer uma cópia do vetor iria ocupar mais de 100% da memória.